# Google fonts not display on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this source that looks perfectly in the desktop browser, but when I check on the mobile I get another different source. Do you have any idea what happens?

are two 2 paragraphs, the first takes this source

```
  Font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
```

the second

```
Font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;



<Link href =" https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial "rel =" stylesheet ">
    <Link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Academy+SC:700" rel = "stylesheet">
```

The second paragraph maintains the source perfectly, the first one when reviewing it on a telephone is changed from source.

This is the page of the problem, it is in the first section, where says HOLA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is not working, so here a few tips + a fix

Remove the whitespaces before and after the links and type everything lowercase.

```
<Link href =" https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial "rel =" stylesheet ">
```

should be this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
```

You use Font-family with an uppercase F, this should be lowercase (font-family)

And now the fix for your problem, you import Academy+SC but in your font-family you use: Amatic SC, this should be Academy SC.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "And now the fix for your problem, you import Academy+SC but in your font-family you use: Amatic SC, this should be Academy SC"  
This was the problem @Dizza love you!